# Determing the Fourier series of piecewise function

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to determine the fourier series of $f(x)$ on $[-2,2]$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2,&-2\leq x \leq 0\\
x, &0 < x \leq 2\\
\end{cases}$$

So I know that,

$$f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big) +  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

Then calculating $A_0,$

$$A_0 = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int _{-2}^{2} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg [\int_{-2}^02dx + \int_0^{2} x \Bigg]= \frac{1}{2}[4+2] = 3 $$

It is is my calculation of $A_n$ where I am not sure if I am following the correct procedure. I just want to make sure I am calculating $A_n$ correctly before I begin $B_n$. Or if someone wants to help me with $B_n$ that would be great too! So here my what I got for $A_n$

$$A_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-2}^{2} f(x) \cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2} \Big) \\ =  \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\int_{-2}^0 2\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) + \int _0^2 x\cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big) \Bigg]\\= \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[2*\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\Big)\Big|_{-2}^0 \Bigg] + \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[x\frac{2}{\pi n}\sin \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2 }\Big) + \frac{4}{n^2\pi ^2}\cos \Big(\frac{n\pi x}{2 }\Big)\Big|_0^2 \Bigg] $$

Now using the fact that $\sin (\pi n) = 0$ and $\cos (\pi n) = (-1)^n$ and plugging in the values of the definite integral, this is where I am not quite sure if I am doing the correct thing. I am pretty sure I have done everything above correctly.

$$\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{4}{\pi n } \sin(\pi n ) + \frac{4}{\pi n } \cos(\pi n )\Bigg] - \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[0 + \frac{4}{\pi ^2 n ^2 } \Bigg] \\ = \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }(-1)^{n} - \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }$$

So right now without calculating $B_n$ I have,

$$f(x) = \frac{3}{2} + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg[\frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }(-1)^{n} - \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 } \Bigg] \cos {\frac{n\pi x }{2}}$$

Comment: Correct to me!.

Comment: @MyGlasses so then $B_n$ is a similar process just with $ \sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$ ?

Comment: yes. try to do it!

Comment: alright I will give it a try, thanks

Comment: I forgot to say all coefficients have $\dfrac{1}{L}$ at the first.

Comment: so it is not $\frac{2}{L}$?

Comment: They are $\dfrac{1}{L}$. recheck with your book!

Comment: yes you are correct, thanks again!

Comment: @Myglasses I have edited the post now with your recent knowledge of $\frac{1}{L}$. Does it look correct now?

Comment: OK. nice${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Myglasses do I need to consider when $n$ is even or odd?

Comment: Not need. But it makes you series simpler and well-set.

Comment: could you show me how to do this?

Comment: With considering $(-1)^n-1=0$ for even $n$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{3}{2} + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\Bigg[\frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 }(-1)^{n} - \frac{2}{\pi^2 n^2 } \Bigg] \cos {\frac{n\pi x }{2}} +\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}\sin {\frac{n\pi x }{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{2} + \sum _{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty} - \frac{4}{\pi^2 n^2 }\cos {\frac{n\pi x }{2}} +\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}\sin {\frac{n\pi x }{2}}
\end{align}
isn't so compact here!

Comment: @MyGlasses no it isn't, but thanks. I made another post about finising this fourier series which I believe I have done correctly, and then finding what this series converges to. Is there any chance you could help me on that one determing what it converges to